# how to execute shell script over ssh?

Tags: shell, github

I'm trying to install opentelemtry package on the remote server over ssh. Actually im executing the script from github actions(using below command). if i run same script on server its wokring fine but from github actions at some point its going into hungstate(long time inprogress state) till max build time of github actions(2hrs 13min) then getting failed state. And other script are executing completely but github actions job is not going into completed state. please let me know what i can do?
using below command executing script remotely on github actions
`run: ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i .id_rsa root@$IPaddress "sh /root/script"`

script file

```
cd /usr/ports/edjx-freebsd-ports/opentelemetry-collector
make clean
make deinstall
make makesum
make gomod-vendor
make install
```

Comment: You're not using root ssh logins are you? If you are, it's probably time to stop and figure out a better solution. That is a BIG no no. I also would never trust github to do anything beyond cloning a git repo then doing whatever was required on the target machine, not via github.

Comment: I also hope you understand the security implications of `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`